# Firestore: Query geopoints using bounds (lessThan/moreThan)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query a collection of documents by their geopoints, using a bounding box taken from a map. I have the bounds:

NORTH: 50.730

EAST: -1.861

SOUTH: 50.700

WEST: -1.893

And this is my actual document structure (based on it's values I would expect it to return):

```
document: {
  d: {
    coordinates: GeoPoint [50.72, -1.87]
  }
}
```

This is what I'm trying, but it's not working:

```
db
  .collection('exploreMap')
  .where('d.coordinates.latitude', '<=', NORTH)
  .where('d.coordinates.latitude', '>=', SOUTH)
  // .where('d.coordinates.longitude', '<=', EAST)
  // .where('d.coordinates.longitude', '>=', WEST)
  .limit(80)
  .get()
```

It just returns an empty query, no errors. I have tried both the EAST/WEST query and NORTH/SOUTH, both the same result.

I know I can't do a full box query as Firestore doesn't support .where() on multiple fields, so doing a simple Latitude or Longitude query would be fine. I can then manually filter when the results are returned.

Can someone please advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't tried the GeoPoint object before, but I've somehow come across with [this video](https://youtu.be/lO1S-FAcZU8) on YouTube about Geoquery. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a way to query just longitude or latitude. But if you create `GeoPoint` with the correct latitude it works for me.

This returns all documents from my collection that are between latitude of 35 and 40:

```
var NORTH = new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(40, 0);
var SOUTH = new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(35, 0);

db
  .collection('10k')
  .where('location', '<=', NORTH)
  .where('location', '>=', SOUTH)
```

Working sample: https://jsbin.com/yatisun/edit?js,console

Since Firestore orders geopoints on latitude and then longitude, you can't filter on just longitude. You can only filter on longitude, once know the exact value of the latitudes you want to return (so not a range).

Comment: Ah! Search by actual geopoints! Works amazing, thanks. I've just edited your jsbin to try and do an EAST-WEST search, but I can't get it working. Since the multiple fields (latitude & longitude) restriction no longer applies because it's querying the geopoint itself, shouldn't we be able to do a full NESW bounded search too?

Comment: Sorry, I had mixed up latitude and longitude in my answer. Geopoints are ordered by longitude-and-then-latitude in Firestore, meaning you can only do a range query on longitude. Full geoqueries are not supported at the moment. For more on this, see previous [questions on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firestore+geoquery), or my (warning: long!) [video on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

Comment: Ah I see. Can you think of any way to accomplish a NESW bounding query? I watched your video this morning, and our current app is doing a radius search. But what we really want to do is a bounding search, not using a central point. Is that possible?

Comment: Geohash queries filter on a range, then in my video I additionally filter by distance (in the client-side code), since that is the more common use-case. But I hope the video did a good job of explaining why bounding box queries (currently) are not possible in Firestore: indexes are single-dimension/direction, even in the case of composite indexes. Note that we've moved away from your original question of how to do a query on just longitude or latitude at this point, and my answer shows how to do that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen has any of this changed since you made the video? Has Firestore gained any new abilities that might help?